# jqPlot Styling - How to remove Y axis line?

Tags: jqplot

I'm having a bit of trouble with jqPlot styling. Currently I've got this:

[image]

This took quite a bit of fiddling to get it like this as it is, but now I've got one problem -- the line on the left! I don't know how to remove it, because I don't actually know WHAT it is!

This is the code I've got so far.

```
  plot = $.jqplot('chart', [values], {
    animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
    seriesDefaults: {
      renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
      rendererOptions: {
        varyBarColor: true,
      },
      pointLabels: { 
        show: true,
      },
      shadow: false,
    },
    axes: {
      xaxis: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
        ticks: keys,
        tickOptions: {
          showGridline: false,
          showMark: false,
          fontFamily: 'DosisBold',
          textColor: '#ffffff',
          fontSize: 'larger'
        },
      },
      yaxis: {
        tickOptions: {
          showGridline: false,
          showMark: false,
          showLabel: false,
          shadow: false,
        },
      },

    },
    seriesColors: ["#bc4427", "#df8321", "#949629", "#5e8c41", "#739c9b", "#3483b3"],
    grid: {
      background: '#1d1d1d',
      drawGridLines: false,
      borderWidth: 0.0,
      shadow: false,
    },

    highlighter: { show: false }
  });
```

I have a feeling it may be something to do with the renderer used on the y axis. Currently it's just using the default one (which I assume is the LinearAxisRenderer). If I change it to CategoryAxisRenderer, it gets rid of the annoying line, but then it shows the marks, and makes the numbers on top of the bars incorrect (so probably isn't going to be that useful).

I've also dug through the CSS, looking for the color of the line, #757575 but to no avail. I also changed EVERY SINGLE COLOR in that file to something that stands out (ie, red), but still nothing changes.

I'm not sure if it's a shadow on something, but I've tried just about every way (except the correct way) to remove them; still nothing.

Has anyone had this problem before? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I with still no luck in sorting the issue out using jqPlot options, I found a solution in just hiding the entire y-axis using CSS.

I just added this to the HTML file between the `<style>` tags, though of course you'd be able to put it in whatever stylesheet you're using.

```
.jqplot-grid-canvas {
    display: none;
}
```

Voila! The damned y-axis is finally gone, leaving my graph styling nice and purdy.

Answer (score 8):

I came across this problem today and I noticed that "drawBaseline" of yaxis was overwritten by drawBaseline of the renderer.  One needs to set the drawBaseline option in the rendererOptions as well like so:

```
axes: {
    yaxis: {
        rendererOptions: {drawBaseline: false}
    }
}
```

Take a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a88MS/1/

To see the issue, comment and uncomment line 38.

Line 37 is there for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the:

```
axes: {
    yaxis: {
       showTicks: false
    }
}
```

Otherwise it might be a border then try (but then again you set `borderWidth` to 0 so it should have the same effect):

```
grid:{
    drawBorder: false,
    shadow: false
}
```

[A sample with both options applied.](http://jsfiddle.net/2mCjW/24/)

Also maybe try setting to each axis:

```
tickOptions: {
    showGridline: false
}
```

Comment: I tried each of those options but unfortunately they didn't do the trick... I'll keep bashing away at it. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: @Boro can you please help me that how can I make this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/TfUfD/2/ for one graph, as in output this is showing two graph?

Comment: @PankajKumar I am not sure what is the problem here. I see a single graph there. Please submit a new question where you can detail your problem in depth.

Comment: @Boro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898047/implement-graph-using-jqplot is the question... my colleague posted here. Actually I was asking about single BAR.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following did do the trick:

I had set `borderWidth : 0` which exactly was the problem, as setting it activated it! Removing it solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this same issue however I really didn't want to fix it with custom css.

I finally managed to figure out you can pass the gridLineColor attribute so you can hide that annoying line on the left hand side from the jqPlot graph parameters.

```
grid: {
  gridLineColor: "#FFFFFF" //or whatever background color you have
}
```