# Implement graph using jQplot

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jqplot

My need is to implement following graph

[image]

*I know about [stacked chart](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php), but here there are axis points labels (In my need there is no any axes point labels), and this is from Y-axis.*

I am confused how can I implement it.

Can you please help me? Any link will also be helpful.

---

Update :

I am trying a code snippet

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
      var line1 = [14];
      var line2 = [77];
      var plot4 = $.jqplot('test2', [line1, line2], {
          title: '1 Mobility Test Graph',
          animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
          stackSeries: true, 
          seriesDefaults: {
              renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
              rendererOptions:{barPadding : 0, barMargin : 5, barDirection: 'horizontal'}, 
              pointLabels:{location : 'e', edgeTolerance : 0, hideZeros: true, show : true},
              shadowAngle : 135,
              lineWidth : 0,
              showLine: true
          },
          axesDefaults : {
                show : false,
                tickOptions : {
                    show : false
                }
            },
          axes: {
              yaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer}
          },
          grid:{
                borderWidth:0, 
                shadow:false
            },
          legend: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
                show:true,
                rendererOptions:{
                    numberRows:1,
                    numberColumns: 3,
                    disableIEFading: false
                },
                location: 'n',
                placement : 'outsideGrid',
                marginTop: '5px',
                showSwatch:false
          }
      });
      $(".jqplot-xaxis-tick").hide();
      $(".jqplot-yaxis-tick").hide();
    });
</script>
```

But this doesn't give me any output. When I remove `barDirection: 'horizontal'` its working fine. Please help me, what is wrong...

Here I got [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/TfUfD/2/) , but it works for two graphs..... how can I make for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you after something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TfUfD/12/)? You have a single stacked horizontal bar there.
As per [examples in doc](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/bar-charts.html) with horizontal bar chart you must give the chart an array of series where each one has values as two values arrays ([x,y]) where x is value and y is series id.

Or another option would be to give the chart a single array of single value arrays, as [shown here](http://jsfiddle.net/TfUfD/14/).

Comment: Yes you are right... I am looking for the same... but how can I show points labels in center of section?

Comment: Hi Boro can you help me for my another question pliz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955524/pointlable-alignment-in-jqplot